# Swift quadratic curves path not closing with a curve

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have an array of CGPoints I am drawing a set of curves based on this array. What I am seeing though is that the "shape" does not close.

```
let counterPath = UIBezierPath()
counterPath.move(to: counterPoints![0])

for (index, _) in counterPoints!.enumerated() {
    if index % 2 == 0 {
        if (index + 2) < counterPoints!.count {
            counterPath.addQuadCurve(to: counterPoints![index + 2], controlPoint: counterPoints![index + 1])
        } else {
            //This should close the shape
            counterPath.addQuadCurve(to: counterPoints![0], controlPoint: counterPoints![counterPoints!.count - 1])
        }
    }
}

counterPath.close()
```

Each of the points are on the circumference of a circle. The even points are slightly "higher" (they sit just above the circumference) with all the odd points sitting slightly "lower" (just below the circumference).

Whats happening is that the last curve is not being drawn. I know usually you just call path.close() but I need it to close with a quad curve.

The overall shape looks like an inside out flower.

Example of what it looks like:

[image: Shape Picture]

This is the array of CGPoints:

```
[(288.079231262207, 109.933921813965), (244.400169372559, 102.082759857178), (227.010290145874, 61.2527008056641), (193.637225151062, 90.5069541931152), (150.87366104126, 78.6449432373047), (152.937526702881, 122.97599029541), (117.0, 149.01433874201), (152.945823669434, 175.041234970093), (150.89608001709, 219.372932434082), (193.656756401062, 207.497505187988), (227.038249969482, 236.740921020508), (244.415832519531, 195.904750823975), (288.091667175293, 188.040241241455), (267.0, 148.99356841296), (207.0, 149.0), (267.0, 148.999997138029)]
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information? E. g. Array of points you use and screenshots.

Comment: @fewlinesofcode I included a picture above

Comment: I believe that `UIBezierPath` is closed. Can you try to remove the gray circle?

Comment: There needs to be a curve from array.count - 2 to Index 0 with array.count - 1 as the control point. There's no curve there currently, hence its a sharp end at array.count - 1

Comment: Can you provide simplified version of the code you using, so i can try it in a playground? In that case i will try to help to resolve this task.

Comment: I included the array of CGPoints above, just need a quad curve to close the "shape", that end picture has 2 shapes. That last curve for one of the paths is not there hence there's a sharp "end"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182707/discussion-between-fewlinesofcode-and-alexander).

Comment: @fewlinesofcode I got it to work, the last 2 points in the array are duplicates hence the modulo conditional got mixed up so the points don't line up. Hence they weren't drawn